# gemspec is broken, cli won't run

Tags: ruby

I keep running into a problem, this gemspec is invalid.  Can someone please help me?

```
lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require "Practical/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "Practical"
  spec.version       = Practical::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["'D'"]
  spec.email         = ["'@gmail.com'"]

spec.summary       = %q{TODO: Write a short summary, because 
RubyGems requires one.}
spec.description   = %q{TODO: Write a longer description or delete 
this line.}
spec.homepage      = "TODO: Put your gem's website or public repo 
URL here."
spec.license       = "MIT"

# Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either 
set the 'allowed_push_host'
# to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow 
pushing to any host.
if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "TODO: Set to 
'http://mygemserver.com'"

spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage
spec.metadata["source_code_uri"] = "TODO: Put your gem's public repo 
URL here."
spec.metadata["changelog_uri"] = "TODO: Put your gem's CHANGELOG.md 
URL here."
  else
raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against "
  "public gem pushes."
end

# Specify which files should be added to the gem when it is 
released.
# The `git ls-files -z` loads the files in the RubyGem that have 
been added into git.
spec.files         = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)) do
`git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| 
f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
end
spec.bindir        = "exe"
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| 
File.basename(f) }
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.17"
spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"

spec.add_dependency "nokogiri"`enter code here`
end
```

I'm not sure what changed.  This worked a few months ago, but now it's broken.  Basically, I'm stuck just getting this to run, the interpreter keeps telling me I have an error in my gemspec.  I can't find it.

Comment: Could you please include the actual command you're trying to run - are you loading this in the consolse? Trying to build the gem? And also the actual error message.

Comment: Also, the way this is formatted here, with hard line breaks in some of the comments, makes this invalid ruby. If that is just an artifact of posting the code here, it would help if you posted it *exactly* as on your local machine.

Comment: To run this gem, I am cd'ing to the directory, and running ./bin/practical, the name of the gem.

Comment: Sorry, but without at least the actual error message nobody will be able to help...